# Go-Gorm `has many` does not work under anonymous field

Tags: go-gorm

I am new to golang gorm, and recently encountered an issue with Association.

The struct I created is:

```
type DeliveryItem struct {
  ..........
  Targets  []TargetType     `json:"targets" gorm:"foreignkey:FK"`
}
```

I create a struct called TargetType like this:

```
type TargetType struct {
    name            string
    FK      int             
}
```

So If i post some data that has an array of targets, it will store data to the delivery item table first (but without targets data), and it will store the targets into a separate table. Everything works with the above structure.

However if i create an anonymous field and put `Targets` inside the anonymous field, then gorm does not insert those targets data into the table. It looks like it does not recognize a relation between DeliveryItem and TargetType

Here is the sample that does not work (for simplicity I did not provide the exact code):

```
type DeliveryItem struct {
  ..........
  CommonDetails 
}

type CommonDetails struct {
  ................
  Targets  []TargetType     `json:"targets" gorm:"foreignkey:FK"`
}

type TargetType struct {
    name            string
    FK      int             
}
```

Did I miss anything for gorm tag to make it work or is Gorm not supporting such kind of behavior? I checked the gorm doc, and its only talk about the first one I provided which works, but I just want to is it possible to make the my failed case work?

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if your failed case could work, as the structure of the underlying fields is fundamentally different. You can see the difference running the code sample below.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type DeliveryItemEmbedded struct {
    CommonDetails
}

type DeliveryItem struct {
    Targets []TargetType `json:"targets" gorm:"foreignkey:FK"`
}

type CommonDetails struct {
    Targets []TargetType `json:"targets" gorm:"foreignkey:FK"`
}

type TargetType struct {
    name string
    FK   int
}

func main() {

    targets := []TargetType{
        TargetType{
            name: "target 1",
            FK:   2,
        },
    }

    cd := CommonDetails{
        Targets: targets,
    }

    die := DeliveryItemEmbedded{
        cd,
    }

    di := DeliveryItem{
        Targets: targets,
    }

    fmt.Printf("embedded: %+v\n", die)
    fmt.Printf("non-embedded: %+v\n", di)
}
```

gives:

```
embedded: {CommonDetails:{Targets:[{name:target 1 FK:2}]}}
non-embedded: {Targets:[{name:target 1 FK:2}]}
```

I'm not familiar with how gorm works under the hood, but I would be surprised if it was able to resolve the CommonDetails indirection. Unfortunately I don't think using the embedding is going to work with gorm in this instance.